# Getting empty rows while filling components of a listview using customadapter

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to access list of details of all `missed calls` from my phone.
I am just trying to access `first 50` missed calls.

The problem is that when some of the rows in the `listview` are filled and some are empty.

This is how it looks i.e blank rows.

[image]

This is the  java file in which i am trying to access the call details.

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView call;
    ListView l;
    int count = 0, k = 0;
    static int flag = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);
            int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
            int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
            int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
            int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
            int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
            int count = 0;
            int dircode = 0;
            String[] array = new String[50];
            int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, param = 0;
int len=0;
            while (managedCursor.moveToNext()  &&len<50) {
                param = 0;
                String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
                String namee = managedCursor.getString(name);
                String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
                String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
                Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
                String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
                String dir = null;
                if (flag == 1) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE) {
                        dir = "MISSED";
                        sb.append("\nName: " + namee + "\nPhone Number:  " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:  " + dir + " \nCall Date:   " + callDayTime
                                + " \nCall duration in sec :   " + callDuration);
                    }
                    param = 1;
                }
                if (flag == 2) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE) {
                        dir = "RECEIVED";
                        sb.append("\nName: " + namee + "\nPhone Number:  " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:  " + dir + " \nCall Date:   " + callDayTime
                                + " \nCall duration in sec :   " + callDuration);
                    }
                    param = 1;
                }
                if (flag == 3) {
                    Log.d("asd", "inside flag3");
                    if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE) {
                        dir = "DIALLED";
                        sb.append("\nName: " + namee + "\nPhone Number:  " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:  " + dir + " \nCall Date:   "
                                + callDayTime
                                + " \nCall duration in sec :   " + callDuration);
                    }
                    param = 1;

                }
                if (flag == 4) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE)
                        count1++;
                    if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE)
                        count2++;
                    if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE)
                        count3++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (param == 1) {
                    array[k] = new String(sb);
                    k++;len++;

                }
                sb.setLength(0);//flushing the buffer
            }
            if (flag == 4) {
                sb.append("Missed Type : " + count1 + "\nReceived type : " + count2 + "\nDialled type: " + count3);
                array[k] = String.valueOf(sb);
                k++;
            }

            l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);//creating listview
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if(array[i]==null)
                   Log.d("asd","NULLLLLL "+ i);
                else
                     Log.d("asd","NOT NULL "+i);
            }
            l.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, array));
            managedCursor.close();
        }catch (SecurityException e){}
    }
}
```

> CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String[] your_array_list;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,String [] your_array_list)
    {
this.your_array_list=your_array_list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return your_array_list.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_row, null);
            TextView textView= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            textView.setText(your_array_list[position]);
            return rowView;
    }
}
```

To verify that all `50` items are not null,i cheked that if some of them are null using this code---

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i]==null)
               Log.d("asd","NULLLLLL "+ i);
            else
                 Log.d("asd","NOT NULL "+i);
        }
```

But all 50 iterations are printing `NOT NULL`.

So,if the strings in the `array` of strings are not null,then why some of the rows in listview are blank ?

Can someone help me with this problem ?

Comment: Few months back I made same app like this. But what I did was used a `CursorLoaded` instead as it aromatically creates a new thread and executes it on that thread without freezing the UI. Did you try debugging this code? If yes please post what did you find.

Comment: @ Saran Sankaran, now i added the snapshot.may be now my problem is clear.

Comment: Snapshot is too small unable to understand anything. Pleas also try debugging the app.

Comment: do u mean to say that i should show the output in `debug console` of android studio. or i should put `Log` statements in my code to see the flow of execution ?

Comment: @ Saran Sankaran ,increased the size of snapshot,now it is visible.

Comment: @a874 Please provide a full code of the "while" cycle. Looks like you init sb in every cycle, but fill this variable only for missed calls. If you want to get only missed calls you need to move "array[k] = new String(sb);k++" inside the "if".

Comment: @ Alexey Rogovoy, uploaded the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move "param=1" statements into internal if statements.
What is the problem. For example, flag==1. But the call type is not MISSED_TYPE:

```
...
if (flag == 1) {
  if (Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE) {
    dir = "MISSED";
    sb.append("\nName: " + namee + "\nPhone Number:  " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:  " + dir + " \nCall Date:   " + callDayTime
      + " \nCall duration in sec :   " + callDuration);
  }
  param = 1;
}
...
```

So, your sb will be empty, but you set param to 1 and this empty sb will be added to the array. You should replace all if statements with:

```
...
if (flag == 1 && Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE) {
  dir = "MISSED";
  sb.append("\nName: " + namee + "\nPhone Number:  " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:  " + dir + " \nCall Date:   " + callDayTime
    + " \nCall duration in sec :   " + callDuration);
  param = 1;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a `flag` variable is initialized 0 but is never incremented/decremented.

This `flag` is responsible for the storing data into the `StringBuffer`

The reason you are getting not null for all the index in the array is because you are initializing each index with a `StringBuffer` passed into the constructor.

So please fix the `flag` variable in your code. This should fix your problem. Also you can see whats the value stored in each index with this piece of code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "data at " + i + ": " + array[i])
}
```

Substitue `LOG_TAG` with suitable value.

Comment: @ Saran Sankaran , flag is a static variable here,whose value is set to 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 in previous activity before this activity starts.That' why when this activity starts flag value is not 0.  correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @a874 did you try adding that for loop to check the data at each index of the array?